# How can I get username and remote machine name when user is connecting via RDC?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using `SessionSwitch` of `SystemEvents` class to detect remote desktop connection and I need to know username of currently connecting user and remote machine name (from which user is connecting). How can I get this data in my Windows Service?

I have found `Environment.UserName` but it's not what I need.

Thanks in advance.